# Every class in java only allow to have one subclass, why Polymorphism allow to have multiple subclass for inheritance?

Tags: java

First of all, thank you for your knowledges. My questions as below:
1)Every class in java only allow to have one subclass, why Polymorphism allow to have multiple subclass for inheritance?
2) Pls provide a example or sample code of Polymorphism for the explaination of the Polymorphism (we will use Polymorphism in what kind of situation?).

I did search from W3school, it stated every class in java only allow to have one subclass, while i go through the Polymorphism section, the sample code showed me there have multiple subclass for the Polymorphism and make me confused.

```
class Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}

class Pig extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The dog says: bow wow");
  }
}

class MyMainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal myAnimal = new Animal();  // Create a Animal object
    Animal myPig = new Pig();  // Create a Pig object
    Animal myDog = new Dog();  // Create a Dog object

    myAnimal.animalSound();
    myPig.animalSound();
    myDog.animalSound();
  }
}
```

Hope to have the explanation of the character, usage of the Polymorphism and we will use Polymorphism in what kind of situation ( to create what kind of operations on the program ) .

Comment: *Every class in java only allow to have one subclass* That is not correct. One superclass. Not one subclass.

Comment: This question seems to be based on a simple understanding or misreading of something that W3Schools has said.  FWIW, I can't find any page on W3Schools that says anything like what you are claiming it says.  Please provide a reference to the page where you got this information.

Comment: This is not correct and I doubt any Java site or instructor would say such a thing. As Stephen said, please post a link to the site that is giving you this information.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in Java can extend by only one class, that's true. But that's not the entire **`Polymorphism`** concept. `Polymorphism` is having many forms. I can see this could be your confusion. Having many forms doesn't imply a class should be extends from multiple classes. As a example if we take your own code snippet;

```
class Animal {

  public void animalSound() {
    System.out.println("The animal makes a sound");
  }
}
```

If you know proper Object Orientation(OO), you should able to match real world with your programming, also you should see `Animal` can't be a class, because `Animal`s are doesn't exist in real world. It's just a common category we put all living and moving (with many more attributes and behaviors) creatures. All the animals have common set of attributes of behaviors (Due to the evolution). Your animal should be something like this;

```
interface Animal {

    public void animalSound();

    public void eat();
}
```

You can't define an `animalSound` in the this `interface Animal`, because `Animal` doesn't have one particular sound but many. In Java, once you use the correct type to define `Animal`, Java itself prohibit you to implement `animalSound()` function.

As you're example, if I correct your `Dog` implementation;

```
abstract class Dog implements Animal {

    public abstract void animalSound();

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Dog is eating");
    }
}
```

> I've introduces a new behavior `eat` to `Animal` to make the point.

Same as `Animal`, `Dog` is another abstract type which you categorize certain set of Animals by their attributes and behaviors. No `Dog` is actually exists. But I've made this `abstract class` hence there're some behaviors that all `Dog`s somewhat do in the same way. In my case it is `eat`. Therefore I can override `eat()` function in `Dog`, rather than override it in the sub classes. Still I assume `animalSound` in each `Dogs` are different.

In the below `Pig` class (`abstract`), I've done the same.

```
abstract class Pig implements Animal {

    public abstract void animalSound();

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Pig is eating");
    }
}
```

Now you can see, `eat()` function has two different implementations (Forms) in both `Dog` and `Pig` classes. That's what **Polymorphism**.

Let me elaborate this more. Now we create a actual "concrete" class for a object that actually exists in the real world.

```
class Riley extends Dog {

    public void animalSound() {
        System.out.println("Riley is barking");
    }
}

class Bingo extends Dog {

    public void animalSound() {
        System.out.println("Bingo is barking");
    }
}
```

Now, `animalSound` has again two different implementation(Forms). In Java, abstract functions must be implemented in the first concrete sub-type unless it's already implemented. Therefore, we must implement this `animalSound()` function. Also this `class Riley extends Dog` is a `is a` relationship due to the inheritance.

The usage of **`Polymorphism`** depends on the requirement. As an example, In Java Swing, `JFrame` and `Frame` both are ultimately inherited/extended from `javax.awt.Window` class, because both needed to have pretty much similar behaviors that only differs by their attributes.

Before you go into implement OO concepts in Java, you must have at least fundamental understanding about classes, interfaces, overriding and overloading. Don't use classes to implement everything. That's where you got this confusion.

Comment: Thank you, Sachith Dickwella. I will go through more on OO concept reading materials. At the same time, do you have any recommendation for video/youtube that giving really good clarification for OO concept in Java? or the materials that provide clarification with the example together.

Comment: This would be helpful to you -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. Start from the "Getting Started" topic. Second topic give you an insight about Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html